# dynamically created form depending on <select> does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a website which must display particular forms for various products depending on the value that the user selects (in `<select>`) - so a number various forms are created dynamically in a loop by means of a javascript function (`buildform()` ). The code does not work, e.g. the forms are not created/appended to the wrappers. I narrowed down the problem where i think the problem relates to a different values for the jquery selectors/div-id's `(#ecorpproductwrapper"+ecorp_eprodselectid)`.
When I use (just as a test) `#ecorpproductwrapper"` (without the variable `ecorp_eprodselectid;` see also in code below under ALTERNATIVE WORKS) the code works fine, e.g. the forms are built. I checked by means of the console that the `ecorpproductwrapper"+ecorp_eprodselectid` values are the same for the div-id's and jquery selectors, so I dont understand what goes wrong?

Pls see the simplified code below:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i==){

  var ecorp_eprodselectid; //will have various values

  //function to build form depending on selected value in <select class= eprodtype"+ecorp_eprodselectid >
  $(".eprodtype"+ecorp_eprodselectid).focus(function () {
    var previous;
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    previous = this.value; //old select value
   }).change(function() {
    var optionsform = buildform(this.value);
    console.log('append form'+optionsform);
    //NEXT 2 lines doe NOT WORK
    $("#ecorpproductwrapper"+ecorp_eprodselectid).children().remove(); //remove previous form
    $("#ecorpproductwrapper"+ecorp_eprodselectid).append(optionsform);

    //ALTERNATIVE works: $('#ecorpproductwrapper').children().remove(); //remove previous tariif struct form
    //ALTERNATIVE works: $('#ecorpproductwrapper').append(optionsform);
    var str = "#ecorpproductwrapper"+ecorp_eprodselectid;
    console.log('STRING ECORP PRODUCT APPEND: '+str);
    console.log('change eprod val: '+this.value);
    previous = this.value;
  });//$("").focus(function () {

}//for i

//function to build form
var buildform = function(ecorp_eproductid) {
//some code here

//NEXT LINE does not work:

   form += '<td> <div id="ecorpproductwrapper'+ ecorp_eprodselectid+'"> </div>  </td> </tr>'; //cell with wrapper for ecorp product info
   //ALTERNATIVE WORKS: form += '<td> <div id="ecorpproductwrapper"> </div>  </td> </tr>'; //cell with wrapper for ecorp product info

  //some code here; returns form
  }//function buildform
```

Comment: create fiddle of your code

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add ecorp_eprodselectid in your function.

```
var buildform = function(ecorp_eprodselectid ) {
```

Comment: you are correct in saying that the function argument was missing, but this was type error when copying the code to this site. E.g., it's not the cause. thnx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Few things we assume concerning given text above:

- You know this.value works
- console.log shows optionsform have HTML that it should have. Not said in OP but if not, the function does not work. function seems to be missing already `var buildform = function(someVar)` as noted by [buysDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976909/2699725)

As I cannot see your code, I would try first clear everything 100% by chaning this:

```
$("#ecorpproductwrapper"+ecorp_eprodselectid).children().remove();
```

to:

```
$("#ecorpproductwrapper"+ecorp_eprodselectid).html("");
```

Then:

```
$("#ecorpproductwrapper"+ecorp_eprodselectid).html(optionsform);
```

No need for append if you have no intention to keep anything in DIV.

If you have text also in (#ecorpproductwrapper"+ecorp_eprodselectid) which is why you use children(), consider selecting the DIV that can be cleared.

If that still does not work, something is left out that needs consideration.

Comment: thnx for your comments and your tip about html(). I just discovered that the ecorp_eprodselectid variable does not contain unique values, so some divs are created with the same id. Still have to figure out how to change that code, but I assume that's the problem...